# Using text field in form in access 2010 to retrieve data from another access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 10 MS Access databases, each larger than the 2 GB limit.

Now I need to create a form in new Access database using the filters in a textbox like, EMPID, EMP NAME, File Name, and Date filters.

Using these filters, I need to get the data in a new table from those 10 databases. For example, employee data file is more than 5 GB, so I separated it into 3 different Access databases. Now, I need to check an employee detail in the newly created form by entering the emp id. The code should check in all the 3 different database for employee data one by one and give me the details in one table in the newly created database which has the form.

I am trying to build this and I am new to Access, you help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed your English and capitalization issues in the post.  Please edit the post and show us your metadata for the original database and the new databases.  And it would help to see your code so far.

Comment: Hi Rohit,Thanks for your valuable response !

Comment: I found the solution ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your frontend database, *link* (or attach if you like) each database/table in question, then create and run normal queries to look up the records and values you need. There is not magic in this.

That said, move the database(s) to an engine that can hold the original size, like the free *MySQL* database, and connect to this via ODBC.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your valuable response ! I didn't think from this perspective ! Now, I am good to go ! :)

Comment: OK, great. Then please close the question.